# Get character number position of tag in dom from a specific point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an unknown amount of html tags within in or the depth of them. HTML inside the div is just for example it could be any amount of tags and depth to the tags.

```
<div id="content">
    <p> Hello this is
        <ul>
            <li>**{I CLICK HERE}**A test<p> and some more</p></li>
        </ul>
        Lorem ipsum
    </p>
</div>
```

If I click on the **{I CLICK HERE}** what I would like to get is the character number position from the #content div to the start of the parent tag of what was clicked. So in this example I would want the character count from #content div of the "li" tag.

The end goal creating a bookmark system I can go back to after saving the position in the database and when this content is reloaded in the future I can wrap that tag or put a class on it to be able to scrollTo that position.

So far I can grab the node but not sure how to get that position of it.

```
$("#content").click(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
});
```

My thinking is once I have the position I save that into the database. When the page reloads I insert a anchor span tag into that position and then use that to scrollTo. I will use server-side code to place in the anchor points on later page loads.

Or, if there is a better way to achieve the end result of being able to use javascript to return (scrollTo) the clicked spot when the page is reloaded please let me know. Data will be saved in a database and pulled back out on a new page-load.

[image]

Comment: What do you expect the 'character count' to be in this example?

Comment: @DavidThomas 22 or 26 (or right around there I just counted on screen either side of tag) it could be either or as long as it's consistent and I can get back to that spot at a later date when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Just to (try) and be absolutely clear, the character count you're looking for would the characters represented by the selection-highlight of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVWwv.png) of the `innerHTML` string or something else? And I'm sorry if I appear to be nit-picking, but I'm still not quite sure what you're referring to, which makes it a difficult question to try and answer.

Comment: I guess your load that ``<li>`` elements dynamically, Why don't set unique ``id`` attributes to every item?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes that would be correct in the image.

Comment: @Gonzalo The text inside #content is for example a full chapter of an educational textbook. I am trying to let users bookmark spots in the text whatever the text may be. The contents are not dynamically created but just pulled from a database of text from chapters that's already been converted to html.

Comment: Just wondering if you already have an idea how to, for example, highlight the character at the recorded position?

Comment: @Sébastien I plan to insert a span tag with unique id at a specified character count after the dom is loaded that I can scrollTo so I am not highlighting any text.

Comment: I meant how are you going to count back to the recorded letter?

Comment: @Sébastien If I have the position in front of the tag I am looking for say character count is 50. I insert the span tag at character 50 (I will be doing this in PHP before the text is send back to browser). which I already know will have a fixed length (to account for multiple bookmarks and characters counts shifting around once I insert one). So I guess the answer I think you are asking for is I will be adding the bookmark spots back in server-side.

Comment: OK I get it, I thought you would have to do it in the browser as well.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but perhaps if you take a look at this demo it's my best guess at what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/td7of37y/

Comment: @DavidThomas I think that might work I'll play with it but even if it's a little off I think I can work with it and get what I need. Thanks, you can put that as an answer.

Comment: Are you able to explain where you feel it is, or might be, a little off? I'm more than happy to take the time to post a correct answer if I'm able :)

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry it looks correct and what I am looking for I have a habit of not confirming things until they are completely working on my end I just started this system so until I build the rest of the bookmark system and it's all working. My head is looking at the whole system done and working but my question here was specific to just this which you did answer and from looking at the output does look like what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to this problem is the following:

```
function innerHTMLCharCountFrom(event) {

  // here we retrieve the node upon which the event,
  // for which the function was listening, was fired,
  // and retrieve its outerHTML (the HTML string of its
  // contents and both opening, and closing, tags):
  let needle = event.target.outerHTML,

    // 'this' is the node upon which the event-listener
    // was bound, and passed from EventTarget.addEventListener();
    // here we retrieve its innerHTML:
    haystack = this.innerHTML,

    // we use String.prototype.substring() to get a section
    // of the innerHTML String from the start index of 0 to
    // the index returned by String.prototype.indexOf(),
    // which is the starting position of the event.target's
    // opening tag (specifically the index of the '<' character
    // in that opening tag):
    temp = haystack.substring(0, haystack.indexOf(needle)),

    // here we create an Object to contain both the found String,
    // the innerHTML of the 'this' node until the beginning '<'
    // of the event.target node ('innerHTMLString') and the length
    // of that String of HTML ('length'):
    result = {
      'innerHTMLString': temp,
      'length': temp.length
    }

  // logging the result Object to the console:
  console.log(result);

  // returning the result Object to the calling context:
  return result;
}

// using document.querySelector() to use a CSS selector to identify
// the element upon which we wish to bind the event-listener:
document.querySelector('#content')

  // binding the 'innerHTMLCharCountFrom()' function (note the
  // deliberate lack of parentheses) as the event-handler for
  // the 'click' event:
  .addEventListener('click', innerHTMLCharCountFrom);
```

```js
function innerHTMLCharCountFrom(event) {

  let needle = event.target.outerHTML,
    haystack = this.innerHTML,
    temp = haystack.substring(0, haystack.indexOf(needle)),
    result = {
      'innerHTMLString': temp,
      'length': temp.length
    }

  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
document.querySelector('#content').addEventListener('click', innerHTMLCharCountFrom);
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p> Hello this is</p>
  <ul>
    <li>**{I CLICK HERE}**A test
      <p> and some more</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/td7of37y/).

Comment: Thanks. It works when I put in short demo content and plug it into my php that inserts a anchor tag to scroll to but stops working when I put the real chapter content in. I believe there is some sort of issue counting characters and differences between the php and the javascript. I do not know what yet when I try putting in tabs, new lines, extra spaces different dom structures to test it all seems to work fine so I am not sure what is causing the count issue differences between the server side and client side. Stops working = Character counts are different between server and client.

Comment: One of the problems you're likely facing is that in the PHP scripts there are, likely, different character counts because of code indentation and the possible use of `\t` to (amongst other characters) to tidy up the presentation in the HTML document. I'm not sure what to suggest as an alternative, but I'll try and think of an alternative approach.